# Map function return if

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return only the user that matches with the id in the code below. How do I make it return "Not Working" only when the id does not match?

```
const database = {
    users: [
        {
            id: '123',
            name: 'Shevy',
            email: 'shevy@gmail.com',
            password: 'soccer',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        },

        {
            id: '124',
            name: 'Benny',
            email: 'benny@gmail.com',
            password: 'java',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        }
    ]
}

let prime = 123

const mapArray = database.users.map((users) => {
      if (Number(users.id) === prime) {
          return users;
      }else {
          return "Not Working"
      }
             
    });
console.log(mapArray);
```

This returns

```
[ { id: '123', 
    name: 'Shevy', 
    email: 'shevy@gmail.com', 
    password: 'soccer', 
    entries: 0, 
    joined: Thu Aug 13 2020 20:00:14 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time) }, 
  'Not Working' ]
```

I want to only return a matched user.

Comment: use `find` instead of `map`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: You're probably looking for `filter` or `find`, not `map` which always creates one output value per array element.

Comment: I see I am using the wrong method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to provide a default value in case no element matches.

```js
const database = {
    users: [
        {
            id: '123',
            name: 'Shevy',
            email: 'shevy@gmail.com',
            password: 'soccer',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        },
        {
            id: '124',
            name: 'Benny',
            email: 'benny@gmail.com',
            password: 'java',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        }
    ]
};
const getUser = search => database.users.find(({id})=>+id===search) ?? 'Not working';
console.log(getUser(123));
console.log(getUser(9999));
```